# How to assign to an HTML element without knowing id/class/tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not talking about jquery at all, but with jquery, it's easy to work with object. Like this:

```
$(selector)
```

So, `selector` can be: a string (can contain id, class name, tag name, attribute...) or an object. I called it: `wrap the selector by $()`.

Can I do same thing with javascript (`document.get(selector)`)?

I've made a function which accepts an HTML object. I want to change the style of it.

Html:

```
<div></div>
```

Script:

```
var changeCSS = function (selector) {
    // I DON'T WANT TO USE jQuery HERE

    // these function doesn't work to target the object (I'd tried)
    // because I'm not sure the selector has an id, class name... or not

    // document.getElementById
    // document.getElementsByClassName
    // document.getElementsByName
    // document.getElementsByTagName
    // document.querySelector

    // my goal looks like: (wrap the selector by 'get' function)
    selector = document.get(selector);

    selector.style.width = '100px';
    selector.style.height = '100px';
};

let selector = $('div')[0]; // not contain id, class name...
changeCSS(selector);
```

In my project, `changeCSS` is a plugin, it doesn't require jquery before using. But I've used jquery in another place.

Totally, I want to know how can I convert (an HTML object, not a string)

```
<div></div>
```

to a selector?

Thank you!

Comment: The only reason you would want to do this is because you have a bad design. Or what is the reason that this element has no class or id?

Comment: @HerrDerb So, why must an HTML element have an id or a class name?

Comment: So you can address it. Why do we have names?

Comment: @clone is it possible to recognize you without your name???

Comment: I want to select every paragraph inside a given article. Why should I have to make them members of a class in order to describe them? "p descendants of an article with the id foo" is quite sufficient.

Comment: Lots of ways to traverse the dom to target elements with unknown or no attributes. Depends on what you are trying to accomplish and what html structure looks like

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll('div');` [more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) methods accept a string containing a selector and return an Element or non-live NodeList respectively.

You can call them on `document` or an element object.

Comment: I'd tried to use `querySelector` with `$('div')[0]`. It logged: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLBodyElement]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: @clone — The argument you pass must, as I said, be a string containing a selector. You seem to be passing your `<body>` element. That isn't a string.

Comment: So, must have an id or a class name, you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @clone — No. You can use any selector (including ones which include combinators).

Comment: If you already have an element … then you don't need to get the element. You already have it.

Comment: Yup. I `already have it`. I just want to pass it to a function as a parameter. That's okay, passing successful. Then, how to use it? That's my problem :))) But thanks, maybe I should change the design.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML element(s).
>
> jQuery selectors are used to "find" (or select) HTML elements based on
>   their name, id, classes, types, attributes, values of attributes and
>   much more. It's based on the existing CSS Selectors, and in addition,
>   it has some own custom selectors.

If you are trying to replicate the selector functionality of jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(.class or tag or #id);
```

Comment: querySelector has nothing to do with ES5

Comment: but with jquery, I can target `$($('div')[0])`. `$('div')[0]` is an HTML element, not a string.

Comment: @Quentin my mistake